# how to read the output of netstat -ano?

Tags: networking

I ran the below command in windows 10:
C:>netstat -ano

and i get a bunch of ip addresses.

How do I know the number after 127.0.0.1:49274 represent what ?
Active Connections

Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID

TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         127.0.0.1:49274        ESTABLISHED     4940

Also, what does 192.168.1.3:49291 represent in below output?

TCP    192.168.1.3:49291      216.58.221.68:443      ESTABLISHED     2500

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my understanding.

1. The number after the IP address is the **port number**. For example, if at the beginning is TCP, the number means a TCP port.
2. For the meaning of `TCP 192.168.1.3:49291 216.58.221.68:443 ESTABLISHED 2500`:

   **Local TCP port 49291** relying on IP 192.168.1.3 has established a connection to the **remote TCP port 443** relying on 216.58.221.68
    And the **2500** means the Process ID is 2500 (As usual, we can check the Task Manager to see what process/program is using this process)

Finally, for more information about [netstat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat), we can refer to the following link.

Comment: Thanks OOOO, is it possible to find out the remote TCP is coming from which URL and what country etc?

Comment: As I search, you can refer to the link:https://www.whois365.com/en/ip/216.58.221.68?w365id=c7e0861df92fdf83db0a3e91a6fccc5c

Comment: it shows private or reserved address.  So there is no way we could tell all about the ip address where it is coming from is it?

Comment: The PTR of the IP is `sin10s01-in-f4.1e100.net`